# Textbox only accept digits, letters and back space; the 1st character entered for the textbox cannot be a digit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am working on this program and I have a problem that I cant figure out.

So I have a textbox that  only accept digits, letters and back space; the 1st
character entered for the textbox cannot be a digit; the length of textbox is at most 6. The textboxe will reject any invalid chars, including any extra chars or a digit
entered as the first char for username.

I have the following code for it, but it is not working and I can't figure out why.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    Dim char1 As Char = e.KeyChar
    If (char1 >= 48 AndAlso char1 <= 57) Then
        If ((Me.txtUserName.Text.Length = 6) Or Not Me.txtUserName.SelectionStart) Then
            Interaction.Beep()
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    ElseIf ((char1 >= 97 AndAlso char1 <= 122 OrElse char1 >= 65 AndAlso char1 <= 90)) Then
        If (Me.txtUserName.Text.Length = 6) Then
            Interaction.Beep()
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    ElseIf (char1 <> 8) Then
        Interaction.Beep()
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use a MaskedEdit control or validate the entry when they are done?  users typically do like like being scolded or beeped at for simple typos

Comment: Those number are `ASCII`, refer this http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason why your code is not working is because you've omitted the handles clause of your KeyPress event:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
```

However, you're trying to reinvent the wheel. I would suggest using existing options and there are essentially two simple solutions that I'd recommend.

**The first option** is to validate the input as it is entered which is what you're trying to do now, only the simplest method of doing this is via the [MaskedTextBox](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidqbTF2eLXAhULxoMKHWxHAgQQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AOvVaw2GCDsrOj4WunuKJZw50D0i) control. In this case, you would set the [AsciiOnly Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.asciionly(v=vs.110).aspx) to True and then set the [Mask property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx) of the control to something along these lines:

```
Mask: A09999
```

The translation of the mask is:

```
A: Required one alphabetical letter (a-z or A-Z).
0: Required one digit (0-9)
9: Up to four optional digits (0-9)
```

**The second option** is to validate the input after it has been entered, e.g. a user clicking a *"next"* Button. The quickest method of doing this, though overkill, would be to validate the input using the [RegEx.IsMatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The pattern used is slightly different than the mask example used earlier, here is the RegEx equivalent to the mask:

```
Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[a-zA-Z]\d{1,5}")
If r.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text) Then
   '... proceed
Else
   'Invalid input
End If
```

The translation of the RegEx is:

```
[a-zA-Z]: Match any letter a-z regardless of case
\d{1, 5}: Match atleast one and up to five digits
```

Comment: Nice answer! Though I have a question: Why are you matching `\d\d{0,4}` in your Regex instead of just `\d{1,5}`?

Comment: @VisualVincent - I worked up the example in haste and free-typed it, but that is a good catch. I'm going to edit my answer to update the RegEx.